# textarea adding space instead of newline

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

Good day SO, I created a textarea in HTML and I fill it dynamically with content using jQuery from using $.load().  The problem I am having is in IE *only* the newlines do not show if I use 
 tags.  I also attempted to use  and 
 but to no avail.  Nothing seems to work.  I'm not sure what I can do to add line breaks.

A little extra back story.  I am dynamically getting this information from vbscript and creating it all as a string to add to the textarea.  I tried using vbCrLf and that does not work either.  It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not IE.

In IE it shows as the following:

`&#13;` shows as a space
everything else hows up as text (i.e. `<br/>` will show as "`<br/>`" as text itself in the textarea)

Any help would be great.  Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**  Added sample code

```
$('#data_holder_id').load('get_query_data.asp', function(response, status, xhr){
    switch(status){
        case "success":
            $('#text_area_id').html(xhr.responseText);
        break;
        case "error":
            console.log(xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText + " : " + xhr.responseText);
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you filling this textarea? Please, post the code sample used.

Comment: I updated the post to show sample code.  The asp page just writes what I need as a string that is returned as the responseText

Comment: Try switching `html()` with `val()` and see if it Works.

Comment: When I switch to val it shows all the &nbsp; and <br /> tags in the textarea as text.  I did a replace on the &#13; to make them <br /> tags and that works in IE but fails in Chrome.  Chrome shows the <br /> tags as text.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a -1 as I don't know what the problem is and no one has stated what i was doing wrong.

Comment: Can you also post the code for `get_query_data.asp` please.

Answer (score -1):

The answer probably lies in the html code. TextAreas have hundreds of properties and methods.

innertext, outertext, and value are three ways to set the value. But Value is the most appropiate way.

Wrap property control line endings behaviour.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535904(v=vs.85).aspx